# Zigzag indicator has error Mismatched input 'zigzagHigh' expecting ']'

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

When using pine script editor and entering the code.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Tick-based ZigZag", overlay=true)

var float threshold = input(1, title="Price Change Threshold")

calculateTickZigZag(src) =>
    var float zigzagHigh = na
    var float zigzagLow = na
    
    var float[] result = array.new_float(2)

    // Calculate swing highs and lows
    if (src - array.max(array.slice(array.from(src), 1)) >= threshold)
        zigzagHigh := src
    else if (array.min(array.slice(array.from(src), 1)) - src >= threshold)
        zigzagLow := src

    // Update mutable variables
    array.set(result, 0, zigzagHigh)
    array.set(result, 1, zigzagLow)
    result

[mutable zigzagHigh, mutable zigzagLow] = calculateTickZigZag(close)

// Plot ZigZag lines
plotshape(series=array.get(zigzagHigh, 0), title="Tick ZigZag High", location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.small)
plotshape(series=array.get(zigzagLow, 0), title="Tick ZigZag Low", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, style=shape.triangledown, size=size.small)
```

I receive an error underlining zigzagHigh Mismatched input 'zigzagHigh' expecting ']'. Can anyone tell me whats going on and how to go about fixing it?

Comment: As indicated in the error message, instead of the `zigzagHigh` variable, the compiler expects the tuple to be closed with `]` because the `calculateTickZigZag()` function returns only one array variable, but you have declared a tuple return from the function.

Comment: Also, that's `mutable` identifier in your tuple? that's not a part of Pine syntax and should be removed. Even after doing so, you still got runtime issues with slicing an empty array that should be handled accordingly in the code.